# How to get the output data from streamlit_feedback

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to collect the user's feedback using the streamlit_feedback. below is my code. every time i give the feedback, the output seems to be empty. can anyone please help

```
feedback = streamlit_feedback(
                feedback_type="thumbs",
                optional_text_label="[Optional] Please provide an explanation",
            )
if feedback:
    print(feedback)
```

i dont know how to debug this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work.

```py
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_feedback import streamlit_feedback

feedback = streamlit_feedback(
    feedback_type="thumbs",
    optional_text_label="[Optional] Please provide an explanation",
)

if feedback:
    st.write(feedback)
```

### Output

1. Select the thumb up

[image]

2. Select submit

[image]

3. Result

[image]

Comment: Hi @ferdy, can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841669/need-help-for-my-use-case-using-streamlit. I think I did not framed my question properly in this post